# What are the differences between the Broken Blade films and series?

Tags: broken-blade

I've been watching the Broken Blade "films" (as they're referred to on Wikipedia), and they're each about 50 minutes long. I was reading, however, that they are releasing an anime series. I don't really get why they're releasing a series when they already have a series, so I was wondering what the difference is, both in structure (is the difference only length, or is it also methods of video release, etc.) and content between the film series and the anime series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most significant difference is that the TV series includes, in episode 10, an important battle from the manga of Girge and the Spartans. Otherwise, the TV series is just a generally better edited version of the films with the following (non-exhaustive) changes:

- All audio is `2.0` channels rather than `5.1` like the movies.
- The order of some scenes during the negotiation in the first film were rearranged for a better and more linear flow.
- Scenes like a passer-by remarking on Sigyn's blushing face (first film) and the monologues of newly appointed [Mileni Team members](http://breakblade.wikia.com/wiki/Mileni_Team) (fourth film) were removed.
- A short [TV special](https://myanimelist.net/anime/30573/Break_Blade__Virgins_War) (Virgin's War) is included in the Blu-ray Box release of the TV series, because Nike died differently than in the films. It's supposed to be watched after episode 10.
- There are also [6 short voice-acted picture dramas](https://anidb.net/anime/10426#episodes) included in the Blu-ray Box release adding some filler-style stories.
- Some scenes were played in like 1.25x speed, especially those from the sixth film.
- Music was added, changed or delayed for the scenes after Cleo shot at Rygart (third film), when Cleo was changing clothes for the sleeping Sigyn (fourth film), and when Girge appeared on a cliff and smirked before diving off to attack Nike (fourth film), respectively.
- New OP and ED songs and animations.

Originally, a spinoff OVA centering around the past of the Golem Delphine and its mysterious creation was [planned](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-02-02/broken-blade-films-updated-for-tv-with-spinoff-ova-in-the-works), but sadly it had been [cancelled](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-12-28/broken-blade-robot-original-video-anime-cancelled/.110414).

Comment: I can only find the 6-movie collection available for purchase. Is the TV series lost to time or something?

Comment: It might be because the TV edition blu-ray box has limited copies. I did find the TV series on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Animation-Broken-Blade-Blu-Ray-BCXA-897/dp/B00IZU75GO), which includes a novel among other things (more info on the [official site](https://breakblade.jp/blu-ray/)).